# Is it a good idea to publish a research paper about the simulation of BB84 protocol?

Tags: simulation, cryptography, research, bb84

I'm an engineering student. As my end of year project I've simulated BB84 protocol using simulaqron(python). I'm thinking about publishing a paper about this simulation.
I haven't published any research paper before, do you have any suggestions about where to publish? or about how to represent my ideas?

Comment: I'm an engineering student. And I'm also thinking of doing my project on BB84 protocol but I don't know where to start.
could you please provide me with the documents and references or anything that helped you in your research?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it depends on the level of detail of your simulation. SimulaQron does not take into account noise, so I presume your simulation is only functional. Many BB84 functional simulations have been developed so far, and no one was so interesting to deserve publication in a research paper.

Notice also that BB84 is the reference example in the following tutorial by the authors of SimulaQron:

http://www.simulaqron.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/instructions_2018_2.pdf

If you want to simulate BB84 in a detailed fashion, you may try [QuISP](https://aqua.sfc.wide.ad.jp/quisp_website/), a novel simulation tool whose focus is "on protocol design and emergent behavior of complex, heterogeneous networks at large scale, while keeping the physical layer as realistic as possible."

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! but with Simulaqron we can simulate noisy qubits.             In my simulation I used cascade protocol for error correction with noisy qubits.

Comment: This is very good news! Can you provide a link to the documentation of the simulation of noisy qubits?

Comment: this is an example https://softwarequtech.github.io/CQC-Python/qber.html?highlight=noise , but now I find that This noise is probabilistic  and  should not be used to benchmark the performence of protocols in noisy settings. As a beginner I didn't pay attention to this detail before :)